# Accessing JSON object keys having spaces

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have a following object:

```
{ "id": "109",
  "No. of interfaces": "4" }
```

Following works fine for the "id" key:

```
alert(obj.id);      // Works fine!
```

But if keys have spaces, then I cannot access their values using the dot notation e.g.

```
alert(obj."No. of interfaces");  // Syntax error
```

How can I access values, whose key names have spaces using the dot notation? Is it even possible with the dot notation? Or do I have to use another way?

Comment: this question is a mistake, it works with the brackets

Comment: Note that [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). What you have there is just a plain object.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnScheffer. Modified the question's language to make the intention more clear.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

The way to do this is via the bracket notation.

```js
var test = {
    "id": "109",
    "No. of interfaces": "4"
}
alert(test["No. of interfaces"]);
```

For more info read out here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Thank you for referencing the documentation. It is surprising how many answers lack this important detail.

Comment: What's difference between the question and answer?

Comment: The answer uses bracket notation `test['No. of interfaces']` instead of dot notation `test."No. of interfaces"`.

Comment: How do you accomplish the same thing when doing object deconstructing?

`const { Pricing, Location, data[0]["Product 1"] } = data[0]` << doesn't work

`const { Pricing, Location, ["Product 1"] } = data[0]` << doesn't work

Answer (score 13):

The answer of Pardeep Jain can be useful for static data, but what if we have an array in JSON?

For example, we have i values and get the value of id field

```
alert(obj[i].id); //works!
```

But what if we need key with spaces?

In this case, the following construction can help (without point between [] blocks):

```
alert(obj[i]["No. of interfaces"]); //works too!
```

Comment: -1. No need to list every variation of what kind of expression can replace `test` in Pardeep Jain’s answer, this is just adding noise to the topic. What about `f()["No. of interfaces"]`? What about `((obj)[i])["No. of interfaces"]` ? Etc.