# Json and dynamic Key

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON Object which is dynamically created based on user interaction, the dynamic key will change every time

example JSON

```
{
"normalkey": "John Smith",
"dynamickey ": "testing"
}
```

is there any way to assign the dynamic key name without knowing the key name for example.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ROOT+"controlpanel/menuBuilder",
    data: "clicked="+menu,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data)
    {   
        $('#foo').html(data.normalKey); 
        $('#bar').html(data.dynamicKey); 

    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: not a duplicate of the above, this isnt a white space related issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an javascript object you can use jQuery's `$.each()` method to get the key names:

```
success: function(data)
{   
    $.each(data, function(key, item){
       console.log(key); // this gets you the key names
    });
}
```

---

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SXJu/)

---

As per your comment

*how would i assign key 2 to a variable without using its name?*

```
var o = {
    "normalkey": "John Smith",
    "dynamickey ": "testing"
};
var a = []; // declare an empty array.
$.each(o, function(key, item){
    a.push(key); // push the keys in it.
});
var dynkey = a.pop(); // .pop() gets you the dynamickey here as 
                      // this is the last item in the array.

console.log(dynkey); // this logs = dynamickey
```

---

#### [Another Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SXJu/1/)

---

#### Description about .pop() @ MDN Docs:

> The pop method removes the last element from an array and returns that value to the caller.

---

So with your last comment:

```
success: function(data)
{   
   var a = [];
   $.each(data, function(key, item){
      a.push(key); // this gets you the key names
   });
   var dynkey = a.pop();

   $('#container').html(data[dynkey]); // <----here you have to do this.

}
```

Comment: that works i get  
normalKey  
dynamicKey  
  
how would i assign key 2 to a variable without using its name?

Comment: @user3524311 see the updated answer with fiddle link, readout the comments in the updated answer.

Comment: one last question, if i then wanted to use the dynkey could i do it like this, `$('#container').html(data.dynkey);`

Comment: @user3524311 Well in short i would say no. you cannot get it that way.

Comment: You can do this: `$('#container').html(data[dynkey]);`

Answer (score 2):

when space come in name then use `[]`  [Bracket notation pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
success: function(data)
    {   
        $('#foo').html(data["normal key"]); 
        $('#bar').html(data["dynamic key"]); 

    }
```

**updated**
to get key use **[jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**

```
$.each(data, function(key, item){
       console.log(key); // here you get the key names
    });
```

Comment: `[]` is called [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

Comment: Hi, its not the space thats the issue the dynamic key will be different every time, so next time it could be dynamic key 2 for example. My question is how do i access the key without knowing its name?