# Syntax for Angular expression where JSON key has an embedded blank

Tags: json, angularjs, space

I am working with a trading partner who sends me JSON with embedded spaces in the keys.  For example

[{"BANK ID":89769876976,"Account Number":789698769876,"Account Type":"CHECKING","Balance":1187.65...

and I cannot find a way to access the keys using angular {{ }} expressions.  Any clues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing JSON object keys having spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces)

Comment: maybe you can add more context? it looks like yourvar['your key'] should be enough

Comment: I have tried {{'t.BANK ID'}} {{['t.BANK ID']}} {{t.[BANK ID]}} and {{t.['BANK ID']}} and none of them work.  If I change the JSON key to BANK_ID, it works great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the bracket notation (*without the dot*)

```
<div ng-repeat="acct in accounts">
  Bank Id: {{ acct['BANK ID'] }},
  Account Number: {{ acct['Account Number'] }}, 
  Type: {{ acct['Account Type'] }},
  Balance: {{ acct.Balance }}
</div>
```

Here is a <kbd>[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IzzWNepjkFO0l8Iv5tc7?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: thanks JoseM.  That was maybe the only permutation I hadn't thought about.  Very strange.