# jquery Jtable add custom data to json

Tags: jquery, jtable

I have been struggling with this all day.

My jTable app works fine. 
It does the queries in the database and puts them in a table.
The JSON that jTable receiving is like this.

```
{
  "Result": "OK",
  "Records": {
    "3": {
        "id": "518",
        "tableUID": "",
        "user_id": "1795",
        "username": "pnk"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "517",
        "tableUID": "",
        "user_id": "1795",
        "username": "plk"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "516",
        "tableUID": "",
        "user_id": "1797",
        "username": "d9"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "515",
        "tableUID": "",
        "user_id": "1795",
        "username": "plkr"
    },
    "extra info": "some data that was generated by php and mysql"
  }
}
```

Is the JSON stored in a variable in jQuery? If so how can I access this variable?

Basically my question is:
How do I get the `extra info` bit out of the JSON with Javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing JSON object keys having spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
// assuming above JSON string is stored in 'data' variable
var json = JSON.parse(data); 
alert(json.extra_info); //avoid space in variable name
//or
alert(json\[extra info\]);
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces)

Comment: Thanks Anjibman, this might work. so the json is stored in the 'data' variable? Ill try it with the jtable recordsloaded option.