# display data using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to display data in the value field of dictionary using Ajax. I know the format to display, but stuck in displaying one of the fields. Code is here :

```
$.each(result, function(index, element) {
      alert(element.Place);
      alert(element.Unique Name);
   });
```

`element.Unique Name` doesn't work as there is a space in between( It is **Unique Name** not **UniqueName**). Could you guys help me out displaying this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it work, try **element[Unique Name]**

Comment: I had tried it before and it doesn't work :( @Gopinath Shiva

Comment: can u show me the html part, to check for other possibilities...

Comment: In short, I have a table with some 50 rows. I want to append the rows with the values I get from Ajax call to the already existing table @Gopinath Shiva

Comment: in that case you can use **.text() or .val()** on the selector element?

Comment: But I want that one particular value which comes under Unique Name :( @Gopinath Shiva

Comment: can't you use class,id,tag,attributes to get that value instead of going for element.Unique Name?

Comment: No, I'm taking the data directly from DB and want to append it to a existing table. @Gopinath Shiva

Comment: remove space  in [Unique Name]   
u cannot use space in lke this  #UserAR

Comment: I'm not sure why doesn't work my first suggestion works, as that is the recommended answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces

Comment: Because I din't give the quotes " " @Gopinath Shiva Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: lolzzzzzzzzzzzzzz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle for your answer](http://jsfiddle.net/Justin_sam/vwxog38x/1/)

```
    var data = {
    "employees": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "Unique Name": "Doe"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "Unique Name": "Smith"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "Unique Name": "Jones"
    }]
};

$.each(data, function (index, element) {
    alert(index);
    $.each(element, function (inde, data1) {
        alert(inde);
        alert(data1.firstName);
        alert(data1['Unique Name']);
    });
});
```

I think it may meet your requirements. plz let me know if works.