# Add CSS class to SlickGrid cell, column name includes white space

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I's using SlickGrid, and want to add a css class to cells. But my column name includes  a white space. Assuming the column name is 'Effort Driven', how can I refer this column?

```
grid.setCellCssStyles("key_highlight", {
    3: {
            finish: 'highlight', /* works fine */
            'effort driven': 'highlight' /*does NOT work*/
        }
 });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referencing it with bracket notation it should work,check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces)

have you tried accessing it like

```
key_highlight[3]['effort driven']
```

I'm still a little curious why you have a space in the key of a key value pair

Comment: I figure it out. The SlickGrid column definition has a  id property. I should use column Id (effort-driven), rather than column name.  var columns = [{ id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven" },  . . . ];  Thanks