# Accessing JSON object keys having spaces in Jade

Tags: pug

I'm trying to make a table out of some JSON data in NodeJS/Jade. The table works fine, except that I can't figure out how to reference object keys which contain spaces.

```
tbody
    each row in thing
        tr
            td
                !{row.id} //Works fine
            td
                !{row.["some key"]} //causes the renderer to crash
```

Doing this causes jade to throw a SyntaxError for an unexpected token, so what is the proper way to reference this key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing JSON object keys having spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces)

Comment: Not a duplicate, this is specifically for Jade, not just JavaScript. The normal JS solutions do not work for Jade.

Comment: Jade's interpolation syntax interprets normal JS. Just apply the advice of that question within the Jade interpolation syntax ` !{row['some key']} ` without the period and your code should work as long as there is a matching key.

Answer (score 2):

From the comment by [litel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5149381/litel), you need to remove the leading period from the property reference.

This line:

```
row.["some key"]
```

should be changed to:

```
row["some key"]
```