# How to access Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to read from a JSON array with a nested array which has its value name spaced out. So I get an error whenever I run the code.

```
var error = [
    {
        "LessonName":"Understanding Multiplication",
        "LessonID":"13343",
        "no of questions":[{"Locked":"31","Unlocked":5}]
    },

    {
        "LessonName":"Finding Unknown Values ",
        "LessonID":"13424",
        "no of questions":[{"Locked":"34","Unlocked":5}]
    }
]


function jsd(){
    document.write(error[0].LessonName);
    document.write(error[0].'no of questions'[0].Locked);
}
```

`document.write(error[0]."no of questions"[0].Locked);` Doesn't seem to display.

Comment: use parseJson for it.

Comment: Link to other Stack Overflow response (brackets) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces

Comment: 1.**First** of all don't make space between the keys."no of questions".

 2. **Secondly** the 
`error[0].Locked`
 doesn't exists.

    error[0]["no of questions"][0].Locked
Does exists

Answer (score 2):

You may use a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with brackets for the string.

```
error[0]['no of questions'][0].Locked
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use this syntax for strings with spaces.

```
document.write(error[0]['no of questions'][0].Locked);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked