# How to access a json field with dot in name

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have a sample json to show as follows
how I can display a field "connector.class"?
If I use , it will show nothing since it interpreted as nest json.

```
{
 "connector.class" : "FileGenericSourceConnector",
 "schema.registry.uri" : "http://localhost:8081",
 "cuid" : "597bd1dc7985373920904f81",
 "file.location" : "/home/vagrant/df_data/",
 "tasks.max" : "1",
 "file.glob" : "*.{json,csv}",
 "file.overwrite" : "true",
 "schema.subject" : "test_value",
 "topic" : "stock"
}
```

Comment: See [Attributes with spaces or dots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311400/6564517)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got this working by using [' '] in rest-on-admin

```
<LongTextInput source="connectorConfig.['connector.class']" label="Class Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AOR FunctionField

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#functionfield

```
<FunctionField label="Connector Class" render={record => {record.connector.class} />
```