# Angular2: How to parse nested json data and show it in a dropdown

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template

i need a help .i have a JSON file that i want to parse and get some value from it.

i have `json` in following format:

enter code here

```
{
"node":{
"default":{
"display Name": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

i want to parse display name .
right now only object coming.

Comment: How are you accessing it? This is possibly a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces

Comment: post your code snippet where you are parsing this , also, are you using typescript?

Comment: rephrase  your post to make more sense

Comment: @Timothy yes m using typescript

in my html file m parsing like this,i know there are some problem here 
<div class="c-token" *ngFor="let item of selectedItems;trackBy: trackByFn;let k = index" [hidden]="k > settings.badgeShowLimit-1">
                    <span class="c-label">{{item.label}}</span>
                    <span class="fa fa-remove" (click)="onItemClick(item)" disabled="true"></span>
                </div>
please let me know how should i parse it

Comment: @Timothy  : could you please tell me the equivalent code for multiple label  for below  code:
item.label["Application"]._default["displayName"] (it printed the result)

Comment: How does the code look like? Show us the http request and component code. No one can really help based on this little information. Is that JSON all you get, or is this just part of response?

Answer (score 0):

U can get the object and use "object.default.displayName" to display the name

Comment: i tried  it.but it is throwing a error that display name is undefined property

Comment: remove the spce in " display Name" in ur json file.. change it to displayName or display_Name something like that

Answer (score 0):

Run this code snippet in console. You will get display name.

```
var data = {
    "node":{
    "default":{
    "display Name": "abc"
        }
      }
    }

    console.log("Display Name :: " + data.node.default["display Name"] );
```

Comment: Not working

Cannot read property 'default' of undefined


this error coming.

Comment: Did you tried above snipped in browser console? it is working for me. Ideally this should work, please check your json data. You can also do :::::           data["node"]["default"]["display Name"]